# Insert db fails

Tags: c++, postgresql

```
void InsertEmployeeRec(PGconn *conn, char * fullname)
{
  // Append the SQL statment
  std::string sSQL;
  sSQL.append("INSERT INTO Worker VALUES ('");
  sSQL.append(fullname);
  sSQL.append("')");

  // Execute with sql statement
  PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, sSQL.c_str());

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        printf("Insert employee record failed");
        PQclear(res);
        CloseConn(conn);
    }

  printf("Insert employee record - OK\n");

  // Clear result
  PQclear(res);
}
```

this is my function to insert db and call it like that

```
InsertEmployeeRec(conn,"n");
```

At the end, i get the error:

glibc detected *** /home/mert/workspace1/Project/Debug/Project: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001df4050 ***

What might be the problem?

Comment: add `return;` after `CloseConn(conn);` in the if-statment.

Comment: actually i dont know what are the bound variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `PQclear(res);` twice.

Comment: when i remove the second one, all the erros gone but i does not insert to db

Comment: @user2232205 That is unrelated to your posted question.  If you have a new problem, I suggest marking one of these answers as accepted and posting a new question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one column in the Worker table you will need to declare them:

```
sSQL.append("INSERT INTO Worker (one_column, name, another_one) VALUES ('");
```

You only need to declare the columns without a default value.